# Gettinig an INT at the end of the Serialized JSON

Tags: json, arduino, esp8266, esp32

So I'm updating this as I've gotten JSON OUT however the JSON is followed by an INT

> {"function":"timereport","values":545028}41

```
  #include <ArduinoJson.h>

char owner[] = "";
const int capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(2);
DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);


void setup() {

Serial.begin(115200);


}

void loop() {
  doc["function"]="timereport";
  doc["values"]=millis();
  Serial.println(serializeJson(doc, Serial));
  delay(5000);
}
```

### Second TRY:(Post Still has the INT at the end)

```
char json_string[256];  

http.begin("http://192.168.1.103:2000/hydroapi"); //Specify destination for HTTP request
  http.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
  doc["function"]="timereport";
  doc["values"]=millis();

  serializeJson(doc, json_string);
  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(json_string); //Send the actual POST request
  http.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `serializeJson` prints the json to `Serial` (as that's the stream your passing in) and returns the number of bytes printed, which you're then explicitly printing using `Serial.println`.
Remove the call to `Serial.println` to avoid printing the number of bytes, just call `serializeJson(doc, Serial);`

Comment: Andy. I updateed the comment to remove the seerial and send the string to a char [] but it still has the INT at the end.....